# Avoiding ItemTemplate Duplication With WPF Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have comboboxes that all need to use a converter:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TimespanConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I'm currently pasting this everywhere I need it, but I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this duplication: to be able to do something like:
`<TimeSpanComboBox ...></...>` or something similar?

Comment: Couldn't you just create a `DataTemplate` resource and reuse it? `<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimeSpanComboBoxTemplate}" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an [implicit `DataTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) somewhere in your `Application.Resources`. i.e.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:TimeSpan}">
  <ContentPresenter
        Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TimespanConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can of course also define a key and re-use it explicitly where you need it (e.g. `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TimeSpanTemplate}"`).